# Chrome custom visuals disappear - SameSite not set now blocked

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a Report Server running with custom forms authentication and now have problems with Chrome browser not showing custom visuals.

Looking at the Chrome console shows that Chrome blocks cookies if SameSite is not set and Secure(SSL) is not set to true.

This gives me various errors (with status 401) ...

To the enduser looking at a PowerBI report the only problem is that custom visuals are not shown. The rest of the report works as expected.

Paginate reports (Reporting Services) do work without errors.

Safari (iOS), Firefox, Edge (Chromium) and IE11 do not have this problem, but will in the near future as there are warnings that SameSite in not set - but no errors for now.

I set cookieSameSite="None" and requireSSL="true" in my web.config of the login website where my auth cookie is generated.

The same setting I made in the web.config of the Power BI report server, but I think that Power BI Report Server (Mai 2020) is currently not using the samesite setting.

Setting Chrome flags "SameSite by default cookies" to disabled is a workaround for Chrome - but I don't want to tell my users to disable the setting and get a security issue ... ;-)

Any thoughts what to change to make Chrome and Custom Visuals work again?

Thanks,

Lars

Answer (score 1):

As of PBI Report Server October 2020 this bug is resolved and PBI custom visuals work with custom authentication and all major browsers in their default settings.